# Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module)

Tags: perl, dbi

I want to use the Defects4j dataset,when I do this follow the page of github: 
 https://github.com/rjust/defects4j

```
$ defects4j checkout Lang
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC
   (you may need to install the DBI module)
   (@INC contains:
   /c/Users/Liu Fang/defects4j/framework/lib
   /c/Users/Liu Fang/defects4j/framework
   /c/Users/Liu Fang/defects4j/framework/core
   /c/Users/Liu Fang/defects4j/framework/core
   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/site_perl
   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
   /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .
   ) at /c/Users/Liu Fang/defects4j/framework/core/DB.pm line 43.
```

[Added line breaks for readability]

Comment: The error message says “you may need to install the DBI module” – have you done that? If the documentation of that software doesn't specify its prerequisites, that's an issue with that software and not with Perl or DBI. Compare also this recent bug report: https://github.com/rjust/defects4j/issues/125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) is the most commonly-used Perl database interface library. It is not included as part of the standard Perl distribution. You will, therefore, need to install this module (as the error message says).

If you update your question to give more information about your environment (what operating system, what version of Perl, how Perl was installed) then we will be able to help you install it.

Comment: The operating system is Windows, I was download ActivePerl 5.24.2 for Windows(64-bit) in https://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads.Then one click install. I used git bash to running "$ perldoc -l DBI",It's wrong with"No documentation found for "DBI". But I used cmd to running it ,it's right with"C:\Perl64\lib\DBI.pm"

Comment: @Luisa: Well, as I said, DBI isn't included as part of the standard Perl installation. You'll need to install it separately. As you're using ActivePerl, you can probably install it with PPM.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.I really appreciate it. Now I try to use the PPM install DBI like "ppm install DBI", but it's wrong with :$ ppm install DBI
Can't locate ActivePerl/PPM/limited_inc.pm in @INC (you may need to install the ActivePerl::PPM::limited_inc module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl .) at /c/Perl64/bin/ppm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/Perl64/bin/ppm line 4.

Comment: @Luisa: I'm afraid I'm completely the wrong person to help you with ActiveState questions. I never use Perl on Windows.